# Pass values in different lines to different variables in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file (file1.txt) with records in different lines
Variable1,2018
Variable2,Jun

Now in my script I would like to store the values in different variables.
Example, I would like my end result to be
Year=2018
Period=Jun

I tried the below logic but it is not solving the purpose as it is storing both values in a single variable.

```
 Get-Content "file1.txt" | ForEach-Object {
 $Var=$_.split(",")
 $Year=$Var[1]
 $Period=$Var[1]
 }
```

Please help.

Comment: Show some more contents of your `file1.txt`.

Comment: Give an example of you file in input and result file you hope

Answer (score 1):

You can do Something like this, if you want use variable :

```
$Object=(Get-Content C:\Temp\test.txt).Replace(',', '=') | ConvertFrom-StringData
$Object.Variable1
$Object.Variable2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using a hash like so:

```
$h = @{}
Get-Content "file1.txt" | % {
  $var = $_.split(",")
  $h[$var[0]] = $var[1]
}

$h['Variable1']
```

Or you could use an object like this:

```
$o = New-Object psobject
Get-Content "file1.txt" | % {
  $var = $_.split(",")
  $o | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $var[0] -Value $var[1]
  $h[$var[0]] = $var[1]
}

$o.Variable1
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `new-variable` cmdlet?

```
#get content from your file instead
$str = "Variable1,2018","Variable2,Jun"

foreach ($line in $str)
{
    $line = $line.split(",")
    New-Variable -name $line[0] -Value $line[1]
}
```